# 403 Error and Browser Cache

Tags: laravel, caching

We have a Laravel Application as Back-end running on a Linux Server.
Some times, when reloading the page, the server returns a 403 Error.

This problem is solved if I clear my Browser Cache, but less than 1 minute using the app, the 403 error appears again.

`/public/.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php # This line does the trick

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] </IfModule>
```

Any clue about it?

Comment: Is this the live server (production)? Do you use apache web-server on purpose? Is this shared-hosting?

Comment: What `mods` are you running with your apache installation?